# GdxRuntimeException in AssetManager.update() handleTaskError

Tags: libgdx

I have a game on Google Play and it's most common crash is in AssetManager.update (AssetManager.java:375) which me or testers never got and I can not reproduce it. The stack trace does not give anything to go on from what I can see?

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError (AssetManager.java:570)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update (AssetManager.java:375)
  at com.aperico.game.platformer.screens.SplashScreen.render (SplashScreen.java:94)
  at com.aperico.game.platformer.PlatformerGame.render (PlatformerGame.java:283)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame (AndroidGraphics.java:459)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun (GLSurfaceView.java:1524)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run (GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader (AssetLoadingTask.java:121)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update (AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask (AssetManager.java:498)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update (AssetManager.java:373)
```

SplashScreen.render()

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {


    if (Assets.assetManager.update() && !doneLoading) {

        Assets.addPersistentAnimations();
        Assets.addForestAnimations();
        game.load();
        doneLoading = true;
    }



    stage.act();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.draw();


}
```

Anyone got some clue as to what is going on?

*edit*
This is what I do in addPersistentAnimations() and addForestAnimations()

```
Model model = getModel("data/viking.g3db");
    Model aniModel;
    aniModel = getModel("data/viking_jump2.g3db");
    aniModel.animations.first().id = "jump2";
    model.animations.add(aniModel.animations.first());
```

Comment: The problem is related to the `handleAsyncLoader` loader [which is only called if the asset loader is asynchronous](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetLoadingTask.java#L121). Can you give more information about how  you add the animations inside `addPersistentAnimations` and `addForestAnimations`?

Comment: I got similar errors when exiting the app immediately after its launch (while still loading assets).

Comment: @Miguel Gonzalez well the code never gets to those statements since the exception occurs in Assets.assetManager.update(). But check my edit for how I add animations.

Comment: What are you loading (how does your Assets.assetManager.load(...) statement look)? Are you using a custom made Loader or an existing one? The problem seems to be the file/resource/asset isn't loaded properly

Comment: I am loading everything, fonts, textures, sfx, 3d models using the standard loader. I guess i have to subclass Assetmanager and add some debug since the exception says nothing

Comment: @Korpen That is not true. Yes, the code gets executed in `Assets.assetManager.update()` but when you take a look at the Stack trace it goes even further down the rabbit hole: `Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader (AssetLoadingTask.java:121)`

Comment: @Miguel Gonzalez of course it is true.. "Can you give more information about how you add the animations inside addPersistentAnimations and addForestAnimations" I said that code is never reached and that is true as long as Assets.assetManager.update() returns false..

Comment: @Korpen Ah, misunderstanding. I thought you were refering to the loader code I mentioned. Can you share your project via Github so I can try to reproduce it? Thanks.